# Why is my loop for appending a list not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner trying to create a roster system in which I can enter as many names as I require (hence the loop) and finish the list by pressing enter, which will then print the list for me. My problem with this code is that:

1: The code is printing 'No employees entered' after I break the while True (line 9) loop. Deleting the try, except paragraph gives me a name error.

2: my else statement (line 29) does nothing when I indent line 31 in it, forcing me to use pass and to remove the indentation for the line 31. Line 31 used to be 30 before I added the pass, so it wasn't a blank line that was the issue.

End Goal:

To be able to print the names that I typed in the loop, and to understand why line 29 isn't executing what's indented into it.

I have tried adding an else statement after the break (16), putting the append (13) there and removing the 'del employeelist[-1]' (15). This doesn't work.*I have been told to **return the employeelist** but I have no grasp on how returning works, and despite trying different ways of returning, am unable to solve the issue. I apologise if the answer is obvious, but I'm struggling (based off of the errors I have) to know where to research.

```
def main():
    start()

def start():
    employeelist = []
    #employeecount = 0
    print("Welcome to Lewis's Rostering System")
    print("")
    while True:
        #employeecount += 1
        print ("Please enter an employee's name, or press enter to finish")
        employeename = input("")
        employeelist.append(employeename)
        if employeename == "":
            del employeelist[-1]
            break

main()
try:
    employeelist
except NameError:
    employeelist = "error"
    print("No employees entered")
    print("")
    input("Press enter to continue")
    print("###############################")
    print("")
    start()
else:
    pass
print(employeelist)
input("end")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# define your employeelist outside any function 
employeelist = []

def main():
    start()

def start():

    #employeecount = 0
    print("Welcome to Lewis's Rostering System")
    print("")
    while True:
        #employeecount += 1
        print ("Please enter an employee's name, or press enter to finish")
        employeename = input("")

        if employeename != "":
            employeelist.append(employeename)
        else:
            break

main()

print(employeelist)
input("end")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mahmoud, this worked perfectly. Do you mind explaining the indenting of 'else:' in relation to 'if', and the indenting of 'break' in relation to 'else:'? As a beginner I struggle to understand why break would be indented to the left of else.

Comment: @Lewis’s so sorry i am writing from my mobile app and can’t indent properly

Comment: Please push else back to match if indentation

Comment: That's no problem, that's how I first tested it and it performed well. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `global` keyword when defining the `employeelist` ---

```
def main():
    start()

def start():
    global employeelist
    employeelist = []
    #employeecount = 0
    print("Welcome to Lewis's Rostering System")
    print("")
    while True:
        #employeecount += 1
        print ("Please enter an employee's name, or press enter to finish")
        employeename = input("")
        employeelist.append(employeename)
        if employeename == "":
            del employeelist[-1]
            break

main()
try:
    employeelist
except NameError:
    employeelist = "error"
    print("No employees entered")
    print("")
    input("Press enter to continue")
    print("###############################")
    print("")
    start()
else:
    pass
print(employeelist)
input("end")
```